Date format option not working on genealogytree
I have a genealogytree TeX file that was working just fine when compiling on an old Macbook. I now changed to a Debian based system, and suddenly the file no longer compiles with the required "date format" option.
I can't find how to attach images, but the output of the code below is still in the american date format, rather than in the requested date format.
Here's the source code:
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{bold-extra}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\gtrset{
    processing=database,
    date format=dd.mm.yyyy,
    node size=2.4cm,
    box={fit basedim=7pt,boxsep=2pt,segmentation style=solid,
        halign=left,before upper=\parskip1pt,
        \gtrDBsex, drop fuzzy shadow},
    }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[place text={\newline}{}]{
    parent{
        g[id=node1]{
            female,
            name={\pref{Person}},
            birth={1928-07-03}{Place},
        }
        c[id=brother]{
            male,
            name={\pref{Brother}},
            birth={1931-07-18}{Same place},
        }
        p[id=father]{
            male,
            name={\pref{Father}},
            birth={(ca.) 1897}{Place},,
        }
        p[id=mother]{
            female,
            name={\pref{Mother}},
            birth={1901?}{},
        }
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Welcome! What should the dates look like? I get e.g. 'July 3, 1928'. That doesn't seem to be your target format, but is that what you mean by 'American'?

I didn't look into the package to figure out why, but it works if you define the date format after \begin{document}.

\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\gtrset{
  processing=database,
  node size=2.4cm,
  box={fit basedim=7pt,boxsep=2pt,segmentation style=solid,
    halign=left,before upper=\parskip1pt,
    \gtrDBsex, drop fuzzy shadow},
}
\begin{document}
\gtrset{date format=dd.mm.yyyy}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \genealogytree[place text={\newline}{}]{
    parent{
      g[id=node1]{
        female,
        name={\pref{Person}},
        birth={1928-07-03}{Place},
      }
      c[id=brother]{
        male,
        name={\pref{Brother}},
        birth={1931-07-18}{Same place},
      }
      p[id=father]{
        male,
        name={\pref{Father}},
        birth={(c)1897}{Place},
      }
      p[id=mother]{
        female,
        name={\pref{Mother}},
        birth={1901?}{},
      }
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

